# ExtJs to DJango url query parameters

Tags: django, extjs, vnc

Ok So this is kinda a long question. I am using ExtJS and Django to create a websiteish. Ive search the internet on how to add query parameters to the url when get an IFrame. So bascily I have this which creates a panel in ExtJS which has an html page with in it. I want to be able to pass a port number with in the url so that when it calls the html it will automaticly have the port number to connect to with vnc. My VNC client is noVNC

```
var noVNC = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: "noVNC",
    frame: false,
    title: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: "component",
            autoEl: {
                tag: "iframe",
                src: "/noVNC"
            }
    }]
});
```

At first I thought that I could just do

```
src: "/noVNC?port=5900"
```

However, (through research) I realized you have to edit views.py and urls.py
I think i have urls.py correct

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'kfe.views.index'),
     url(r'^index$', 'kfe.views.index'),
     url(r'^noVNC/(?P<port>\d+)/$' , 'kfe.views.noVNC'),
)
```

But I am not sure how to use the views.py

```
def noVNC(request):
     return render(request, 'noVNC_Auto.html', content_type='text/html')
```

hope that is enough info. If not just tell me

Thanks

Comment: +1 great question. I'm not familiar with noVNC so why do you need the vnc url pattern `"noVNC/5900/"` ? and your view shopuld be `def noVNC(reques, port):` so you can get the port number

Comment: Ok yeah, Im slowly figuring it out. I think I got view.py and urls.py Ill post it again as an answer once I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the way I fixed it was very easily because of my conditions (I did not need any of my arguments in views.py).
So what I did was inside my IFrame html page I did this

```
window.onload = function () {
        con_port = "?port=" + WebUtil.getQueryVar('con_port', null);
```

and inside ExtJS I did this

```
var noVNC = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: "noVNC",
    frame: false,
    title: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: "component",
            autoEl: {
                tag: "iframe",
                src: "/noVNC?con_port=5901"
            }
    }]
});
```

for now I just hard coded in the port number but you can just add your port number to the string like so

```
src: "/noVNC?con_port=590" + port
```

views.py

```
def noVNC(request):
    return render(request, 'noVNC_Auto.html', content_type='text/html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'kfe.views.index'),
    url(r'^index$', 'kfe.views.index'),
    url(r'^noVNC$' , 'kfe.views.noVNC'),
```

Comment: It seems like you've hardcoded the port in your ExtJS is that correct?

Comment: Yup, you can just add the port # to the string so like --- src: "/noVNC?con_port=590" + port

Comment: if that solved your problem i'd put it in the answer and mark it as correct for others who might have the same issue.