# EXT JS load content image data into a window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having trouble loading image data into a draggable window using EXT JS.

The link to a process that streams the image file is in the code.

I've tried using

```
var plotWin = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    title: 'Plot',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    x: 10,
    y: 200,
    loader : {
                url : "http://209.105.242.30/custom/webimg",
                autoLoad : true,
                renderer : 'data'
            },
    plain: true,
    headerPosition: 'top',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        border: false
    }
});
```

and then

```
plotWin.show();
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that url is cross domain, which means that it's not going to be able to load via ajax. If it's an image, why not just embed it?

```
var plotWin = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    title: 'Plot',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    x: 10,
    y: 200,
    plain: true,
    headerPosition: 'top',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'image',
        src: "http://209.105.242.30/custom/webimg"
    }
});
```

Comment: One issue is the src param won't accept a query string like "http://209.105.242.30/custom/webimg?a=4&b=9". looking at the firefox debugger console it only sends the ? an then a {. Any ideas?

Comment: this appears to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672551/extjs-to-django-url-query-parameters